# Sql Database Elastic pool and sku combination is invalid

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template, elastic-database-pool

I am able to create Sql Server, Sql database, sql elastic Pool Successfully using ARM templates. But when I trying to create  new database with existing elastic pool name. I am getting below error.

Without elastic pool id, database is creating successfully.

**Both Sql database Elastic Pool and database are using same location, tier, edition etc.Also When tried in azure portal it created successfully.**

```
 "error": {
"code": "ResourceDeploymentFailure",
"message": "The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'.",
"details": [
  {
    "code": "ElasticPoolSkuCombinationInvalid",
    "message": "Elastic pool 'sqlsamplepool' and sku 'Basic' combination is invalid."
  }
]
```

**ARM Template:**

```
 {
 "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
 "parameters": {
  "collation": {
  "type": "string",
  "metadata": {
    "description": "The collation of the database."
  },
  "defaultValue": "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"
},
"skutier": {
  "type": "string",
  "metadata": {
    "description": "The edition of the database. The DatabaseEditions enumeration contains all the 
    valid editions. e.g. Basic, Premium."
  },
  "allowedValues": [ "Basic", "Standard", "Premium" ],
  "defaultValue": "Basic"
},
"resourcelocation": {
  "type": "string",
  "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]",
  "metadata": {
    "description": "Location for all resources."
  }
},
"sqlservername": {
  "type": "string",
  "metadata": {
    "description": "The name of the sql server."
  }
},
"zoneRedundant": {
  "type": "bool",
  "metadata": {
    "description": "Whether or not this database is zone redundant, which means the replicas of this database will be spread across multiple availability zones."
  },
  "defaultValue": false
},
"sqlElasticPoolName": {
  "type": "string",
  "metadata": {
    "description": "The Elastic Pool name."
  }
},
"databaseName": {
  "type": "string"
}
 },
 "functions": [],
"variables": {  },
  "resources": [
{
  "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases",
  "apiVersion": "2020-08-01-preview",
  "name": "[concat(parameters('sqlservername'),'/',parameter('databaseName'))]",
  "location": "[parameters('resourcelocation')]",
  "sku": {
    "name": "[parameters('skutier')]",
    "tier": "[parameters('skutier')]"
  },
  "properties": {
    "collation": "[parameters('collation')]",
    "zoneRedundant": "[parameters('zoneRedundant')]",
  "elasticPoolId":"[concat('/subscriptions/',subscription().subscriptionId,'/resourceGroups/',resourceGroup().name,'/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/',parameters('sqlservername'),'/elasticPools/',parameters('sqlElasticPoolName'))]"
  }
 }
]
}
```

Comment: To better troubleshoot are you able to provide the ARM for the elastic pool?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what wrong with "2020-08-01-preview" version but its working fine with stable version. below is my partial arm template code that working.

I changed to 2014-04-01 api version.

```
  "comments": "If Elastic Pool Name is defined, then curent database will be added to elastic pool.",
  "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases",
  "apiVersion": "2014-04-01",
  "name": "[concat(parameters('sqlservername'),'/',variables('dbname'))]",
  "location": "[parameters('resourcelocation')]",
  "properties": {
    "collation": "[parameters('collation')]",
    "zoneRedundant": "[parameters('zoneRedundant')]",
    "elasticPoolName":"[if(not(empty(parameters('sqlElasticPoolName'))),parameters('sqlElasticPoolName'),'')]",
    "edition": "[parameters('skutier')]"
  }
```